# BoxLayout.Y_AXIS not working in Swings

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager, boxlayout

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

class MyJPanel extends JPanel {
JButton login, register;

public MyJPanel() {
    login = new JButton("Login");
    register = new JButton("Register");

    this.add(register);
    this.add(login);
}
}

class MyJFrame extends JFrame {
MyJPanel mjp;

public MyJFrame(String title) {
    super(title);

    mjp = new MyJPanel();

    Container ct = getContentPane();
    ct.add(mjp);


    setLayout(new BoxLayout(getContentPane(), BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    setSize(400,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
}
}

class Gui7FirstPage {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    MyJFrame mjf = new MyJFrame("Welcome!");
}
}
```

The above code is aligning the 2 Buttons Login and Register along X-Axis. I intend to stack them up using BoxLayout.Y_AXIS but it doesn't seem to work.

The 2 buttons are aligned horizontally side by side and I want them to be place verically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default a `JPanel` uses a `FlowLayout`, so your `MyJPanel` class is using a `FlowLayout`.

You are adding your buttons to the panel, so the panel needs to use the `BoxLayout`, NOT the content pane.

At the start of the constructor for your class you need:

```
setLayout( new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS) );
```